# Add Admob banner to Screen

Tags: android, admob, banner, banner-ads

Can`t add admob banner as usual:

```
  // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "*********************");
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel2);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But now I am using:

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends Screen {

    private AdView adView;
    public MainMenuScreen(Game game) {

        super(game);    
    }   
----------------------------
public class AndroidFastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    AndroidGame game;
    Bitmap framebuffer;
    .......
```

So how can i use Admob banner in new game app?
If you would like to look at other code just give me call)

Comment: Why can't you add the AdView to your Activity as usual?